# gitlab.com meaning and quotas of storage on project overview page

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab

Can someone tell me whats the meaning of storage on gitlab.com?
I have some project where the files size is 3mb and the storage near to 100gb. 
Where does it come from? 
I am using my own runner with minio cache server.
[image]

Is there any limit on GitLab.com regarding this storage on the free plan?

Here is an example: https://gitlab.com/jerometwell/pynonymizer

Answer (score 1):

See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/file_storage.html which lists all things that contribute to the "storage" number (for example, CI artifacts).

The storage limit is 10 GB per repo (see https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2015/04/08/gitlab-dot-com-storage-limit-raised-to-10gb-per-repo/)

https://gitlab.com/jerometwell/pynonymizer is at 42 MB for Storage. There is no way through the GitLab UI to detail your current Storage, but you are way under quota.

The 42 MB could be attachments in issues, for example.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/file_storage.html is the only documentation I could find regarding storage.

Comment: I am using gitlab runner on my kubernetes cluster and the artifacts are cached on minio. The storage is still increasing, also the artifacts expire. Is this just an ongoing counter? On all the data ever flowed through the pipelines? I still do not understand where is it stored?